# trimming a string in c++

Tags: c++, replace, trim

Hello I have a problem with trimming string in c++. It adds some weird chars at the end of the 
string.

```
string& Napis::subst(char cold, char cnew) { 
    string * s = new string(data); 
    replace(s->begin(),s->end(), cold, cnew);  
    return *s; // takes back string s with changed sign
}
```

Comment: How is this function called? What is it supposed to do? What is `data`? How did you establish that it added weird characters at the end of the string?

Comment: Returning a reference to a string you just allocated is a bad idea - it makes the ownership very unclear. You probably just want to return string and then allocate one locally (i.e. no new) so you can return by value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll bet you are calling `subst` with `cnew` set to zero. You are expecting this to delete the characters, but that's not what it does. It replaces them with zeroes, just as its name suggests.

How about:

```
string Napis::subst(char cold, char cnew) { 
    assert(cnew != 0);
    string s = data; 
    replace(s.begin(), s.end(), cold, cnew);  
    return s; // takes back string s with changed sign
}
```